# How i do filter date range filter in database MVC 5

Tags: asp.net-mvc

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rh692.png)

this is my current code this is my current code i want add filter date range filter in database MVC 5 by referring to the picture, I have done the data show from the database. and find some column
this is my current code this is my current code i want add filter date range filter in database MVC 5 by referring to the picture, I have done the data show from the database. and find some column
this is my current code this is my current code i want add filter date range filter in database MVC 5 by referring to the picture, I have done the data show from the database. and find some column

controller code  :

```
public ActionResult Tables()
        {
            try
            {
                //Creating instance of DatabaseContext class  
                using (boraEntities entities = new boraEntities())
                {
                    var draw = Request.Form.GetValues("draw").FirstOrDefault();
                    var start = Request.Form.GetValues("start").FirstOrDefault();
                    var length = Request.Form.GetValues("length").FirstOrDefault();
                    var sortColumn = Request.Form.GetValues("columns[" + Request.Form.GetValues("order[0][column]").FirstOrDefault() + "][name]").FirstOrDefault();
                    var sortColumnDir = Request.Form.GetValues("order[0][dir]").FirstOrDefault();
                    var searchValue = Request.Form.GetValues("search[value]").FirstOrDefault();
                    //Paging Size (10,20,50,100)    
                    int pageSize = length != null ? Convert.ToInt32(length) : 0;
                    int skip = start != null ? Convert.ToInt32(start) : 0;
                    int recordsTotal = 0;
                    // Getting all Customer data
                    var customerData = (from tempcustomer in entities.Request_5000
                                        select tempcustomer);
                    var username = Session["userName"];
                    var role = Session["role"].ToString().Trim();
                    if (role == "user")
                    {
                        customerData = customerData.Where(m => (m.user_login == username));
                    }
                    //Sorting    
                    if (!(string.IsNullOrEmpty(sortColumn) && string.IsNullOrEmpty(sortColumnDir)))
                    {
                        customerData = customerData.OrderBy(sortColumn + " " + sortColumnDir);
                    }
                    //Search    
                    if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(searchValue))
                    {
                        customerData = customerData.Where(m => (m.citizenic_request == searchValue) || (m.strrequest_byuser == searchValue) || (m.api_request == searchValue));
                    }

                    //total number of rows count     
                    recordsTotal = customerData.Count();
                    //Paging     
                    var data = customerData.Skip(skip).Take(pageSize).ToList();
                    return Json(new { draw = draw, recordsFiltered = recordsTotal, recordsTotal = recordsTotal, data = data });
                }
            }
            catch (Exception)
            {
                throw;
            }

        }
```

view code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width" />
    <title>NT Bora</title>
    ...

    <script>
        $(document).ready(function () {
            function getDateString(date) {
                var pattern = /Date\(([^)]+)\)/;
                var results = pattern.exec(date);
                var dt = new Date(parseFloat(results[1]));
                return (dt.getMonth() + 1) + "/" + dt.getDate() + "/" + dt.getFullYear();
            }
            $("#demoGrid").DataTable({
                "processing": true, // for show progress bar
                "serverSide": true, // for process server side
                "filter": true, // this is for disable filter (search box)
                "orderMulti": false, // for disable multiple column at once
                "pageLength": 5,
                "field": 'date',

                "ajax": {
                    "url": "/Tables/Tables",
                    "type": "POST",
                    "datatype": "json"
                },

                "columnDefs":
                    [{
                        "targets": [0],
                        "visible": false,
                        "searchable": false
                    },
                    {
                        "targets": [5],
                        "searchable": false,
                        "orderable": false
                    },
                    ],

                "columns": [
                    { "data": "id", "name": "id", "autoWidth": true },
                    { "data": "citizenic_request", "name": "citizenic_request", "autoWidth": true },
                    { "data": "user_login", "name": "user_login", "autoWidth": true },
                    { "data": "system_name", "name": "system_name", "autoWidth": true },
                    { "data": "strrequest_byuser", "name": "strrequest_byuser", "autoWidth": true },
                    { "data": "api_request", "name": "strrequest_byuser", "autoWidth": true },
                    { "data": "message", "name": "message", "autoWidth": true },
                    { "data": "createdAt", "name": "createdAt", "render": function (data) { return getDateString(data); } },
                ]

            }).columnFilter({
                "aoColumns": [
                    { "type": "number-range" },
                    { "type": "text" },
                    { "type": "select" },
                    { "type": "date-range" }
                ]
            });
        });
    </script>

</head>
<body>
    <div class="container">
        <br />
        <div style="width:90%; margin:0 auto;">
           
            <table id="demoGrid" class="table table-striped table-bordered dt-responsive nowrap" width="100%" cellspacing="0">
                <thead>
                    <tr>
                        <th>id</th>
                        <th>Citizenic Request</th>
                        <th>Usre</th>
                        <th>System Name</th>
                        <th>Strrequest By User</th>
                        <th>API Name</th>
                        <th>Message</th>
                        <th>Date</th>
                        @*<th>Edit</th>
                    <th>Delete</th>*@
                    </tr>
                </thead>
            </table>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

### Calling datatable on button click

I have modified your code and added what you wanted to do with the datatables. I think you wanted to get the start date and end date from the user and on button click you want to call the datatable to display the records.

```
<div class="container">
    <br />
    <div style="width:90%; margin:0 auto;">
       <div class="col-sm-12">
           <div class="form-inline">
               <div class="form-group">
                   <label class="form-check">Start Date</label>&nbsp;&nbsp;
                   <input type="text" id="st_date" placeholder="dd/MM/yyyy" />
               </div>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
                <div class="form-group">
                   <label class="form-check">End Date</label>&nbsp;&nbsp;
                   <input type="text" id="ed_date" placeholder="dd/MM/yyyy" />
               </div>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
                <div class="form-group">
                   <input type="button" id="find_record" class="btn btn-success" Value="Submit" />
               </div>
           </div>
       </div>

        <table id="demoGrid" style="display:none;" class="table table-striped table-bordered dt-responsive nowrap" width="100%" cellspacing="0">
            <thead>
                <tr>
                    <th>id</th>
                    <th>Citizenic Request</th>
                    <th>Usre</th>
                    <th>System Name</th>
                    <th>Strrequest By User</th>
                    <th>API Name</th>
                    <th>Message</th>
                    <th>Date</th>
                    @*<th>Edit</th>
                <th>Delete</th>*@
                </tr>
            </thead>
        </table>
    </div>
</div>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){
    //date picker control for start date
    $( "#st_date" ).datepicker({
        dateFormat:"dd/mm/yy"
    });
    //date picker control for end date
    $( "#ed_date" ).datepicker({
        dateFormat:"dd/mm/yy"
    });
    //button click event
    $("#find_record").click(function(){
        if($("#st_date").val()!="" && $("#ed_date").val()!="")//Check if the dates are selected
    {
        var start_date=$("#st_date").val(); //get start date value on a varable or you can directly pass the value
        var end_date=$("#ed_date").val();//similary for end date as well
        $("#demoGrid").show();//Display table;
        $("#demoGrid").DataTable({
            "processing": true, // for show progress bar
            "serverSide": true, // for process server side
            "filter": true, // this is for disable filter (search box)
            "orderMulti": false, // for disable multiple column at once
            "pageLength": 5,
            "field": 'date',

            "ajax": {
                "url": "/Tables/Tables",
                "type": "POST",
                "data":JSON.stringify({stdate:start_date,eddate:end_date}),//Pass the start date and end date as per the parameters declared in your method
                "datatype": "json"
            },

            "columnDefs":
                [{
                    "targets": [0],
                    "visible": false,
                    "searchable": false
                },
                {
                    "targets": [5],
                    "searchable": false,
                    "orderable": false
                },
                ],

            "columns": [
                { "data": "id", "name": "id", "autoWidth": true },
                { "data": "citizenic_request", "name": "citizenic_request", "autoWidth": true },
                { "data": "user_login", "name": "user_login", "autoWidth": true },
                { "data": "system_name", "name": "system_name", "autoWidth": true },
                { "data": "strrequest_byuser", "name": "strrequest_byuser", "autoWidth": true },
                { "data": "api_request", "name": "strrequest_byuser", "autoWidth": true },
                { "data": "message", "name": "message", "autoWidth": true },
                { "data": "createdAt", "name": "createdAt", "render": function (data) { return getDateString(data); } },
            ]

        }).columnFilter({
            "aoColumns": [
                { "type": "number-range" },
                { "type": "text" },
                { "type": "select" },
                { "type": "date-range" }
            ]
        });
    }
    else{
        $("#demoGrid").hide();
        alert("Start and end dates are required");
    }
    });        
});
</script>
```

Let me know if it is useful to you.